# Determine when an object nears a point

Tags: distance, geocoding, android, geofencing, uber

Context: When an Uber vehicle is very close to the destination, there is an alert on the driver app that indicates that the destination has arrived. This determination is quite accurate.

Two approaches come to mind wrt implementation:

- Fence with a small radius around the destination
- Distance between current location and Destination

Typically in devices (say android), it is suggested that fences be at least 150m for good results. There is possibility of false alarms as well (based on the accuracy of a location as determined via gps).

What does Uber do to determine if the vehicle is close enough from the destination?

Answer (score 1):

==Distance between current location and Destination also comes in mind. It will be an easy and quiet precise implementation ,with the likes of Voronoid diagram(considering the algorithm behind Voronoid).